# Contact cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java

i have been trying hard to spot my error but to no avail. can someone help me?
I am sure that I am comparing the correct objects

```
    Contact[] sortedList = myContactList.sortContactsByName();
    for (Contact c : sortedList) {
        // TODO using this line means you need to implement what in Contact class?
        // Hint: You need to override a method inherited from Object.

        System.out.println(c);
    }
}



public Contact[] sortContactsByName() {
    Contact[] contactArray = contacts.toArray(new Contact[contacts.size()]);
    // TODO Contact class has to implement Comparable
    // interface for this to work!

    Arrays.sort(contactArray);
    // Don't bother how it works now, sorting in Java
    // will be covered later on.
    return contactArray;
}
```

}

```
public int compareTo(Contact o1){

    return this.name.compareTo( o1.name);
```

Comment: Your error are: you didn't do the `TODO Contact class has to implement Comparable interface for this to work!`

Comment: How did you declare the Contact class ? Does your class implements Comparable ?

Comment: Please post the declaration of your `Contact` class. Is your `compareTo` function a method of that class?

Comment: i did! just that i could nt copy the code here due to constraints. THANK YOU EVERYONE! I solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two solutions for your problem, first one is described by most people here, make your contact to implement `Comparable` interface, this method is good, but it has some limits, ie if you want to have two lists with your contacts, one sorted by firstname second by lastname, you cant do this with this approach

fortunatelly there is method `sort` which takes custom comparator as parameter, with this solution your class doesnt need to be `comparable`, all what you need to do is create your custom comparator ie

```
public class Contact{
 private String name;

public static final Comparator<Contact> BY_NAME_ASC = new Comparator<Contact>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
};

}
```

now all what you need to do to sort your array is `Arrays.sort(contactArray,Contact.BY_NAME_ASC);`

Comment: hey that is amazing. cos i m quite new to java. may i know how the sorting works?

Comment: what is the difference between comparator and comparable?

Comment: @user3327196  Arrays.sort is using merge sort algorithm, more details you can find here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: @user3327196 from Java api:  `Comparable` - This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. `Comparator` - A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the class `Contact` to implement `Comaprable`.

```
class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {
```

Just implementing `compareTo` is not enough without this declaration. Also it is good practice to put an `@Override` annotation above `compareTo`.

Comment: `Comparable<Contact>` is even better to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The class you want to use the interface Comparable with must implement it.

```
class Contact implements Comparable
```

You then implement the method below in the Contact class. You have to remember that this is the first object calling compareTo on the other object of the same type. So you can't access the private variable of name directly in the parameter, use a getter.

```
public int compareTo(Contact o1){ 
    return this.name.compareTo(o1.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@user3327196: You will have to implement Comparable interface to your Contact class.
Code is attached below:

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact contact){
        return this.name.compareTo(contact.name);
    }

}
```